# I am writing a program which ask user to enter time in 24 hour format and diplay closest departute time of schedule flight

Tags: c

minutes,using the 24-hour clock) the pro gramme the displays the departure and arrival time for flight whose departure time is closet to that enter by user?
departure time  arrival time
8:00 am         10:16 am
9:43 am         11:52 am 
11:19 am        1:31 pm
12:47 pm        3:00 pm 
2:00 pm         4:08 pm
3:45 pm         5:55 pm
7:00 pm         9:20 pm
9:45 pm         11:58 pm

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void){

    int dept1,dept2,dept3,dept4,dept5,dept6,dept7,dept8,hh,mm,entertime;

    printf("Enter a time in 24-hour format:");
    scanf("%d:%d",&hh,&mm);


    dept1=8*60;
    dept2=9*60+43;
    dept3=11*60+19;
    dept4=12*60+47;
    dept5=14*60;
    dept6=15*60+45;
    dept7=19*60;
    dept8=21*60+45;

    entertime=hh*60+mm;

    if(entertime<=dept1){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 8:00 A.M,arriving at 10:16 A.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept2){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 9:43 A.M,arriving at 11:52 A.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept3){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 11:19 A.M,arriving at 1:31 P.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept4){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 12:47 P.M,arriving at 3:00 P.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept5){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 02:00 P.M,arriving at 4:08 P.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept6){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 03:45 P.M,arriving at 5:55 P.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept7){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 07:00 P.M,arriving at 9:20 P.M");
    }else if(entertime<=dept8){
        printf("Closet Departure time is 09:45 P.M,arriving at 11:58 P.M");
    }

        return 0;


}
```

i have expressed hour and minute in to for e.g 13:15=13*60+15=795 minute  so it would be closer to 12:47 pm which is 12*60+47=767 minutes

but not getting any output

Comment: add one `else {printf("something");}` after the last `else if`. see if this is getting printed.

Comment: my input is 22:12 @haccks

Comment: getting error after adding the else after last last else if error recived ERROR:expected ',' before '{' token @sakthi kumar

Comment: @user3439385 `22:12` is later(i.e, larger) than any of the time in your code, of course there's no output, because there's no matching condition.

Comment: Can you explain please what is the problem?
And I suggest not adding anything to the string in the `scanf()` function:
i.e. `scanf("%d%d", &hh, &mm);` rather than `scanf("%d:%d", &hh, &mm);`

Comment: @Alextikh problem is that if i enter 13:15(13*60+15=795) then the program should display 12:47 pm departure time as 795 minutes is closer to 767 minutes instead of 2:00 pm is 14*60=840 as the difference between minutes is greater than   as it is between 13:15 and 12:47 basically its a advisory program which advise a customer to check the closest departure time whatever time he enter. as i m a beginner and i find this project under selection statement chapter by using select statement is it possible?

Comment: Try printing hh and mm, see if they are read correctly

Answer (score 0):

> problem is that if i enter 13:15(13*60+15=795) then the program should
>   display 12:47 pm departure time

Since you want the departure time closest to the entered time, you must not compare `entertime` to the departure times, but to the times halfway between to successive departure times, e. g. instead of

```
    if(entertime<=dept1)
```

write

```
    if (entertime <= (dept1+dept2)/2)
```

and at last remove the

```
    if(entertime<=dept8)
```

to enable the user to get the latest flight when none of the earlier ones fits.

Answer (score 0):

Using this way is much easier and you can also use a 2D array to make it even simpler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void){
int hh,mm,entertime;
int dept[8] = {8*60,9*60+43,11*60+19,12*60+47,14*60,15*60+45,19*60,21*60+45};
printf("Enter a time in 24-hour format:");
scanf("%d:%d",&hh,&mm);
entertime=hh*60+mm;

if(entertime<=(dept[0]+dept[1])/2 || entertime>=dept[7]&&entertime<2*60){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 8:00 A.M,arriving at 10:16 A.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[1]+dept[2])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 9:43 A.M,arriving at 11:52 A.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[2]+dept[3])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 11:19 A.M,arriving at 1:31 P.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[3]+dept[4])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 12:47 P.M,arriving at 3:00 P.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[4]+dept[5])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 02:00 P.M,arriving at 4:08 P.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[5]+dept[6])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 03:45 P.M,arriving at 5:55 P.M");
}else if(entertime<=(dept[6]+dept[7])/2){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 07:00 P.M,arriving at 9:20 P.M");
}else if(entertime<=dept[7]){
    printf("Closet Departure time is 09:45 P.M,arriving at 11:58 P.M");
}else{
    printf("Not a valid time input");
}
    return 0;
}
```